# Does having Global Entry reduce the monitoring/checks one gets from customs agents?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, global-entry

I read on this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/149646/1810):

> I don't remember my Global Entry interview in detail, but I certainly got the impression that, by using Global Entry, I am taking personal responsibility for monitoring and checking my own conformance to customs and immigration rules, and in exchange **CBP reduces the amount of their monitoring and checking**.

Does having Global Entry reduce the monitoring/checks one gets from [customs agents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21005/1810)?

Comment: If you have Global Entry, break the rules and they catch you, they're pretty harsh as they feel you ought to know the rules... There have been cases of [people with GE and some fruit having their GE rovoked](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/the-craziest-reasons-people-have-had-global-entry-revoked), so you certainly seem to be held to a higher standard

Answer (score 7):

At my local airport, San Diego, non-GE international arrival passengers have to take their bags off their cart, run them through an X-ray and then see a customs agent.

Using GE, I didn't have to line up, and just rolled my cart past an agent who took/looked at (I don't remember which) my kiosk printout and waved me on. Much more convenient. It was more like going through the green nothing-to-declare lane at Heathrow than my previous experiences arriving at San Diego.

Of course, they can always do random checks, but so far GE seems to be worth it.

Comment: Interesting to hear that SAN normally inspects all non-GE passengers at customs. That's definitely not my experience at other US airports. Most of them you just walk through the exit after collecting your bags, just like in most other parts of the world, though, like you said, there's always a chance of inspection. Granted, given its proximity to the Southern border, smuggling might be a bigger concern at SAN than most airports.

Answer (score 3):

Like another question (to which Patricia Shanahan and I also provided conflicting answers), I will provide the perspective of US Pre-clearance in Canada. I can speak to Halifax, Canada (YHZ). **Basically, there does not appear to be any reduction in the monitoring or checking for using Global Entry at YHZ.**

Passengers using Global Entry didn't have to wait to use the normal Automated Passport Control terminals, and were called by the officers before any of the normal passengers. There is also a specific lineup for clearing the security portion which is handled by CATSA (the Canadian equivalent of TSA).

However as far as *customs and immigration* is concerned, I was still asked a couple quick questions, just like any other passenger. I'm a permanent resident, what was I doing in Canada (tourism), where was I headed (home), how did I get my permanent residence (employment). The rest of the questions would have been asked already by either the APC/GE terminal. I got a stamp and headed on.

Overall, at US Pre-Clearance at YHZ, Global Entry is mostly about getting access to a priority lineup.