# Where to declare goods when using Global Entry in US preclearance at Dublin?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, global-entry, pre-clearance, dub

I recently took a flight from Dublin (DUB) to the US, and so I went through US immigration and customs preclearance in Dublin.  I have Global Entry and used the automated kiosk.  I realized afterwards that I hadn't ever been asked whether I had any goods to declare for customs, and it wasn't clear how I should have declared them (if I had had any).

After entering the preclearance area and having my bags X-rayed, there was a lane for Global Entry with the kiosks.  In the past, when I've used a Global Entry kiosk in other places, it has asked me to select answers to the usual "landing card" questions: any goods to declare, carrying any food, etc.  In this case, the kiosk just took my photo and printed a receipt.  It didn't ask me any questions, and I didn't see any place where I could have selected "goods to declare".  I think it was just "touch screen to begin", "look into the camera", "take receipt to the desk".

Next, there was a desk with a border officer.  I gave him the receipt from the kiosk, and he looked at it and sent me through without asking any questions.

I assumed at this point that there would be another desk where I would be asked customs questions, but in fact after walking away from the first desk, I realized I was already in the gate area, and there were no further checks.

I also didn't notice having gone through a "nothing to declare" channel at any point.

So, if I actually had had goods to declare, what would I have needed to do?  Was there a button on the kiosk that I overlooked?  Was I supposed to proactively announce it to the officer at the desk (I didn't see any signs saying to do so)?  Should I have stood in the regular queue instead of using a kiosk?

Comment: see similar topic (but completely different aspect) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149561/what-is-the-last-point-where-one-can-throw-away-fruits-if-one-has-indicated-not/149567#149567

Comment: Because Immigration comes before Customs, I'd ask at Immigration. Even if you only see eGates, there'll be an Immigration officer somewhere in the vicinity.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica: The problem is that in this case, I don't even know which part of the process was which.  (By "eGates" do you mean the Global Entry kiosks?  They don't have gates.)